# How do I plot the groupby in altair?

Tags: pandas-groupby, altair

[image]

I did groupby by genre and trying to plot using altair and I'm getting the error below.

```python
disney_revenue = disney_movies.assign(inflation_adjusted_gross = disney_movies['inflation_adjusted_gross'].str.strip('$').str.replace(',','').astype(float))
disney_total_revenue = disney_revenue.assign(total_gross = disney_revenue['total_gross'].str.strip('$').str.replace(',','').astype(float))
disney_group = disney_total_revenue.groupby(by='genre')


chart2 = alt.Chart(disney_group, width=500, height=300).mark_circle().encode(
            x='movie_title:N',
            y='inflation_adjusted_gross:Q').properties(title='Total Adjusted Gross per Genre')
chart2
```

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
SchemaValidationError: Invalid specification

        altair.vegalite.v4.api.Chart->0, validating 'type'

        <pandas.core.groupby.generic.DataFrameGroupBy object at 0x7f0611f2ac10> is not of type 'object'
```

Comment: Can you edit your question so that your code is easier to read? As it stands, it's difficult to parse. Here's a guide: https://stackoverflow.com/editing-help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You cannot pass a pandas groupby object to `alt.Chart` – you must pass a dataframe. But if you want to visualize grouped data, you can do that via the Altair encoding syntax. For example, here is a version of the chart you were trying to create, faceted by genre:

```python
alt.Chart(disney_total_revenue).mark_circle().encode(
    x='movie_title:N',
    y='inflation_adjusted_gross:Q',
    facet='genre:N',
).properties(
    title='Total Adjusted Gross per Genre'
)
```